# historical origin of some shortcut combination

Tags: language-agnostic, keyboard-shortcuts, history, convention

yesterday a non programmer friend of mine, asked me about shortcuts. He wants to know why certain actions are binded to some typical shortcut combination.
I know that every program has it's own keyboard shortcuts but there are some that are common to almost all program:

1. <kbd>CTRL+X</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL + C</kbd>/ <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> : cut,copy,paste
2. <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL+Y</kbd> : undo/redo

So, I was wondering, does anyone know about the origins of these conventions? Have these conventions ever been formalized somewhere? Are there any practical or historical reason why these shortcut combinations have been chosen instead of others?

That's just curiosity..

Comment: I guess V is used because it is near to C and X :)

Comment: @yi_H: yes..probably it is. But for example CTRL+Y is not particularly a quick combination to be pressed, but it is quite adopted.

Comment: Not sure if it's related at all, but some keyboard layouts have Z and Y the other way around (German one for example).

Comment: @viraptor: intersting ..never heard about that

Comment: An interesting parallel is the current mess of application-specific touch-screen and mouse gestures, which can be expected to merge into a more coherent set over the next decade or so....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The origins of ctrl z,x,c, and v originate from Xerox PARC. They created the shortcuts way back when in their text editors. They were a R&D group, and their standards became widely adopted. Not sure why though.

Comment: I think that's right.  The choices were made at PARC, and Apple subsequently 'popularised' them by making them standard across applications in the original Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this link should help -

Taken from wiki link below -

"Common User Access (CUA) is a standard for user interfaces to operating systems and computer programs. It was developed by IBM and first published in 1987 as part of their Systems Application Architecture. Used originally in the OS/MVS, VM/CMS, OS/400, OS/2 and Microsoft Windows operating systems, parts of the CUA standard are now implemented in programs for other operating systems, including variants of Unix. It is also used by Java AWT and Swing."

More details - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_User_Access

Comment: Is this before/after/related to the Xerox PARC group?